# Which graded commutative $R$-algebras occur as cup product algebras $H^\ast(X;R)$ of spaces $X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, graded-rings, rational-homotopy-theory

Which graded commutative $R$-algebras occur as cup product algebras $H^\ast(X;R)$ of spaces $X$?

This is a question in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (page 214 Chapter 3). Hatcher says that the problem is solved for $R=\mathbb{Q}$ by a paper [Quillen 1969] which I assume is the one titled "Rational Homotopy Theory". Hatcher also says that the case $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$ is also solved for prime $p$. Now where can I find the reference to this? Also, what kind of prerequisites are needed to understand the solution for $R=\mathbb{Q}$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$?

It would also be great if someone directly addresses the solution, just to give an overview. My thanks in advance.

Comment: There are quite a few books on Rational Homotopy Theory you can consult (I'll leave to you to choose the one that suits you the best), which is a whole area of study (still active at the moment). In that case, the statement is that the homotopy category of simply connected CDGAs over $\mathbb Q$ of finite type (obtained by inverting the quasi-isomorphisms) is equivalent to the homotopy category of simply connected spaces of finite type (obtained by inverting the rational equivalences).

Comment: So essentially, any simply connected cdga of finite type is the cohomology algebra of some rational homotopy type (i.e. of some space $X$ up to rational equivalence). This is kind of a mouthful, and I am not going to write a complete answer, but maybe it gets you in the right direction. Alexander Berglund has some notes on the subject which I find really pleasing to read.

Comment: (In case the space is not simply connected, you need to assume it is nilpotent to start to develop some equivalent version of Sullivan and Quillen's results, but I do not even know what the statements are in that case.)

Comment: Thank you Pedro, I will check out the note by Berglund. I am fuzzy about some of the concepts you've mentioned (quasi-isomorphism) but I will look them up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: My copy of Hatcher says that there are only partial results in the mod $p$ case, not that is solved. The "Hopf invariant one" problem is relevant.

Comment: The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.4002 solves the problem of which polynomial rings can occur, with any coefficients.